# set datetime culture vb from database date record

Tags: database, vbscript, cultureinfo

I have a problem.
How can i set cultureinfo to date, when the date comes from database.

I have database, where is recorded date/time, when a request have arrived.
Now it displays it like this: `2/24/2013 5:41:12 PM` and i want it to display like this `5. toukokuuta 2013`. For more info about that format i want is [here](http://www.basicdatepicker.com/samples/cultureinfo.aspx) It's in line 68 (Finnish)

The code i already have:

```
<script language="VB">
  Imports System
  Imports System.Globalization
  Imports System.Threading

Public Class FormatDate

Public Shared Sub Main()
  Dim dt As DateTime = DateTime.Now
  ' Sets the CurrentCulture property to U.S. English.
  Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = New CultureInfo("fi-FI")
  ' Displays dt, formatted using the ShortDatePattern
  ' and the CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.
  Console.WriteLine(dt.ToString("d. MMMM'ta 'yyyy"))

End Sub
End Class
</script>
```

That code dosen't work for now.
Here is the string, which i want to combine it:

```
<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "pvmaika") %>
```

(that pvmaika is database value, it means datetime)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In front of the page, where you have that 
`<%@ Page Culture="fi-FI" Language="VB"  Debug="true" %>`.
Include `Culture="fi-FI"`.

That will work!

Comment: Thanks, that was the problem, i don't even need extra codes! Perfect